# react, How to put name in JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

```
[
  {
    "key": 14,
    "pid": "test3",
    "name": "test3",
    "gender": "other",
    "age": 3,
    "birth_date": "2020-08-03",
    "regi_date": "2020-08-30T13:47:36.025570Z",
    "fundus": "no image",
    "status": "ready",
    "del_yn": "no",
    "del_date": null
  },
  {
    "key": 13,
    "pid": "test4",
    "name": "test4",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 4,
    "birth_date": "2020-08-04",
    "regi_date": "2020-08-30T13:47:16.174702Z",
    "fundus": "no image",
    "status": "ready",
    "del_yn": "no",
    "del_date": null
    }
]
```

I want to change the json data above to the json data form below

```
 "test": [
      {
        "key": 14,
        "pid": "test3",
        "name": "test3",
        "gender": "other",
        "age": 3,
        "birth_date": "2020-08-03",
        "regi_date": "2020-08-30T13:47:36.025570Z",
        "fundus": "no image",
        "status": "ready",
        "del_yn": "no",
        "del_date": null
      },
      {
        "key": 13,
        "pid": "test4",
        "name": "test4",
        "gender": "male",
        "age": 4,
        "birth_date": "2020-08-04",
        "regi_date": "2020-08-30T13:47:16.174702Z",
        "fundus": "no image",
        "status": "ready",
        "del_yn": "no",
        "del_date": null
        }
    ]
```

When `console.log(JSON.stringify(originData, null, 2));` is executed, it will appear like the picture below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTcf1.png)

How can I put a title in json data?

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify({test: originData}, null, 2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
JSON.stringify({test: originData}, null, 2)
```